# Infinite Loop of layoutAttributesForElementsInRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, infinite-loop, freeze

I have absolutely zero idea why this is happening, but for whatever reason a collection view I am using is infinitely looping the `[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:]` method.

The collection view is inside of my custom navigation bar. In one scenario where I use this custom navigation bar, everything works as expected. In another scenario, it loops infinitely.

- I have experimented with not setting the data source or delegate on the `collectionView`.
- I have tried setting the data source and delegate, but returning `0` for `itemsInSection`.
- I am using auto layout as in the working situation, and I am initialising the custom navigation bar as in the working situation.

In regard to posting code, I am not sure exactly what to post. The infinite loop begins after `[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible]` is called. This method never returns. It was only after time profiling that I discovered that it was this `[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:]` that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same infinite loop problem inside `[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:]` when i was manually updating contentOffset to collectionView with no elements (i.e. when `numberOfItemsInSection` was 0).

Comment: Man, if I just have found your answer 2 days ago.. Big thanx.

Comment: In my case i was calling setNeedsLayout on the collection view's superview (setting the offset wasn't needed)

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the heights of different collection views in a table view so i followed this [UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell — dynamic height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126708/uicollectionview-inside-a-uitableviewcell-dynamic-height). But i mistakenly commented out the `[self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];` because i had thought it would improve scrolling performance. I uncommented it and it worked again! Not sure why it works though