# UICollectionVIew inside a UITableViewCell how to get dynamic height with autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I know that there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126708/uicollectionview-inside-a-uitableviewcell-dynamic-height), but I'd like to give more hints about how I tried to achieve that since the original question doesn't give any advice.
I have a `UITableViewCell` as a subview of the contentView there is a `UICollectionView`, I'd like to have the cell height in function of the collectionview `contentSize`, the table view cell is the collection view delegate and datasource.
The collection view should be fixed without scrolling possibilities in a vertical flow and it should adapt its height on the number of cell lines.
 
To do that I've tried to used the same technique I use with common table view cells. I create a fake cell and keep a reference to it, then in the method `- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` I feed the cell with the data that it should display and then ask to its height for compressed size.
Something like that:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize  size = CGSizeZero;
    NSDictionary * data = self.data[indexPath.row];
    if (data[KEY_CELL_IDENTIFIER] == CellIdentifierPost) {
        NSNumber * cachedHeight = [self.heightCaches objectForKey:[(PostObject*)data[KEY_CELL_DATA] postObjectId]];
        if (cachedHeight) {
            return (CGFloat)[cachedHeight doubleValue];
        }
        [_heightCell configureCellWith:data[KEY_CELL_DATA]];
        size = [_heightCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
        [self.heightCaches setObject:@(size.height) forKey:[(PostObject*)data[KEY_CELL_DATA] postObjectId]];
    }
    else if (data[KEY_CELL_IDENTIFIER] == CellIdentifierComment){
        size = (CGSize) {
            .width = NSIntegerMax,
            .height = 160.f
        };
    }
    else {
        size = (CGSize) {
            .width = NSIntegerMax,
            .height = 50.f
        };
    }

    return size.height;
}
```

This method works really fine for the other cells, but not for this one, the result is a totally compressed cell with almost a zero height.
The problem seems to be due to the inner cells placement. Even if after feeding the data I force the collection view to reload data, it seems to never call the `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` this happens probably because the cell is still not displayed.
Is there a work around?

Comment: Are all the collection view cells the same height?

Comment: I'd add a height constraint to your UICollectionView. Set the height to the cell size + whatever spacing you want.

Comment: That's the point height should be function of the number of cells

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to create a height constraint for your collectionView.

Then, based on the number of cells, you may calculate the height for it, and, at the end, you update that constraint and call **[collectionView setNeedsUpdateConstraints]**