# Both Vertical and Horizontal Scroll Direction in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

Im stuck with the problem to use both vertical and horizontal scroll direction in a UICollectionView in the same UIViewController.

What I've done so far is first a UICollectionView. In top of the UICollectionView I've got a Collection Reusable View. My solution is to implement an other UICollectionView inside of the reusable view but got errors when running the project.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the view returned from -collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath (UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader,<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}) was not retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath: or is nil ((null))
```

So Im actually handling two different CollectionViews in one UIViewController in the same Delegate and Datasource methods.

It is a better approach to build it with a UITablewView? Than add the collectionviews to different UITableViewCells? Or better to start with an UIScrollView and then add two different UICollectionViews to the scrollview?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[AFTabledCollectionView](https://github.com/ashfurrow/AFTabledCollectionView/blob/master/AFTabledCollectionView/AFViewController.m)

Refer above sample code

In this sample code. `UITableView` is there and `UITableviewCell` contains `UICollectionView`(With horizontal direction).

Some more detail from above sample code regarding to your problem

Take one 'UITableView' having 2 section. Its first section would have 'UICollectionView' and second section has 'UICollectionView'.

Comment: As I'm trying to explain in the picture I want to use both vertical and horizontal scroll. The top should be as an carousel and the rest as an normal vertical UICollectionView.

Comment: Okey thanks, but is it possible to adjust the size of the "second" UITableViewCell to be as big as the number of CollectionViewCells inside of the UICollectionView? I tried with UITableViewAutomaticDimension but that will of course not work because the UICollectionViewCell wont be bigger even if there's a lot of cells. @payal-maniyar

Comment: Set with constraint for tableview and give height like below line of code :

`if(indexPath.section > 0)
    {
        return 210.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 188;
    }`
This way you will not face any issue.

Comment: Yes of course I do if it seems to be right. But why should I set the height to 188 in section 2? @payal-maniyar I want it to be dynamic. Should be as big as all the cells in the collectionview. So 188 feels to small..?

Comment: I gave you for example. You can set as much as height yo want.

Comment: Yes I see .. But as I said the UITableViewAutomaticDimension doesn't work with this and I cant set it to a static height. If you want to look at the app TicTail you will see the exact same approach I want to do at their first page. @payal-maniyar

Comment: I followed the steps from this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/33364092/1752699 and that worked out for me. 
Created two different UITableViewCells with two different UICollectionViewCells inside of each of them. Thanx! @payal-maniyar

Comment: welcome. One problem can be solved by many ways. My solution is also correct because right now I am working on it. I have just it implemented before 2 days.

Comment: Okey great! Would you like to share your code in some way so I can look at your solution? Can share my solution as well. @payal-maniyar