# Dynamic CollectionViewCell In TableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, row-height

### Question:

**How To Make `UITableViewCell` Height Dynamic according the `UICollectionViewCell`?**

### View Hierarchy:

> UIViewController
>
> > UITableView
> >
> > > UITableViewCell
> > >
> > > > UICollectionView
> > > >
> > > > > UICollectionViewCell1
> > > > >
> > > > > > Label 1
> > > > >
> > > > > UICollectionViewCell2
> > > > >
> > > > > > Label 2
> > > > >
> > > > > UICollectionViewCell3
> > > > >
> > > > > > Label 3
> > > > >
> > > > > [So on]

### Explanation:

Here `Label1`, `Label2`, `label 3` are have dynamic height and `numberOfRows` in `UICollectionView` is also dynamic. I need Height of `UITableViewCell` according to the `UICollectionViewCell`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### View Hierarchy In `UIViewController`

[image]

### Steps:

1. Bind Delegate And Datasource

- Bind `UITableView` delegate and datasource with the `UIViewController`.
- Bind `UICollectionView` Delegate and datasource with the `UITableViewCell` here `TblCell`.

2. In `UIViewController`

   ```
    class CollectionVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    :
    :

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension // For tableCell Dynamic Height
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200 // For tableCell Estimated Height
    }
    // Above two delegates must be necessary or you can use property for same.


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 // returning 1, as per current single cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TblCell") as! TblCell

        return cell
    }
    }
   ```
3. In `TblCell`

   ```
    class TblCell: UITableViewCell , UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    @IBOutlet var colViewObj: UICollectionView!

    // Array for Label
    var arrData = ["Hello", "How re you?", "rock the world", "Nice to meet you.", "Hey! It is awsome."]


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        self.colViewObj.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

         // Get width of Label As per String characters.
        let aWidth : CGFloat = arrData[indexPath.row].width(withConstraintedHeight: 40, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0))

        return CGSize(width: aWidth + 40 , height: 40)
    }

    // THIS IS THE MOST IMPORTANT METHOD
    //
    // This method tells the auto layout
    // You cannot calculate the collectionView content size in any other place, 
    // because you run into race condition issues.

    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {

        // If the cell's size has to be exactly the content 
        // Size of the collection View, just return the
        // collectionViewLayout's collectionViewContentSize.

        self.colViewObj.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                       width: targetSize.width, height: 600)
        self.colViewObj.layoutIfNeeded() 

        // It Tells what size is required for the CollectionView
        return self.colViewObj.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrData.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ColViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ColViewCell

        cell.lblTitle.text = arrData[indexPath.item]

        cell.lblTitle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.lblTitle.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

        return cell
    }

    }

    extension String {

    func width(withConstraintedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

        return ceil(boundingBox.width)
    }
    }
   ```

### Output:

- **Red Border :** UITableViewCell
- **Yellow Border :** UICollectionViewCell
- **Black Outline :** Label

**with UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**

[image]

**without UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**

[image]

### Reference:

[UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell -- dynamic height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126708/uicollectionview-inside-a-uitableviewcell-dynamic-height#)

### Note :

`TableViewCell` height is based on `collectionview` content size i.e. if same `tableCell` have any other UI component other than `collectionview` or there is top bottom margin for `collectionView` then it won't be calculated. For this, you can create multiple cells in which one cell only contain `collectionview` (Best Approach for now) or you can return your actual `tableViewCell` height in `systemLayoutSizeFitting` by calculation.

Comment: Thank you, man!!! I was looking for this for ages, nothing seemed to be working but this worked perfectly with my use case.

Answer (score 0):

how to give height to cell accorting to text in swift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    let message = "Swift is a powerful and intuitive programming language for macOS, iOS, watchOS and tvOS. Writing Swift code is interactive and fun, the syntax is concise yet expressive, and Swift includes modern features developers love."


    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
    let height = heightForLabel(text: message, font: font, width: self.view.bounds.width )

    if height > 40 {
        return height  
    } else {
        return 40.0;
    }
}


func heightForLabel(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width:width,height:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text

    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}
```