# Dynamic height UICollectionViewCell in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a controller having an UITableView as child view and the UITableView contains the dynamic cell. A horizontal scrollable UICollectionView is added inside the cell and I am showing some text data in UICollectionView. I want the height of the UITableViewRow to adjust according to the provided text to the UICollectionViewCell.

The structure is given following -:

```
UITableView
    UITableViewCell
        UICollectionView (Horizontal scroll having one row only)
            UICollectionViewCell
                UILabel <- The dynamic text will be added to this label.
The UICollectionViewCell width is fixed and the height can be dynamic. When the label text is large, the height of the label will also be changed along with the height of the UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionView and UITableView cell so that the UITableViewCell height matches the height of the label.
```

How can I achieve this in Xcode and swift 3?

Comment: Please refer this  https://possiblemobile.com/2016/02/sizing-uicollectionviewcell-fit-multiline-uilabel/

Comment: Use this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724530/dynamic-collectionviewcell-in-tableviewcell-swift