# How do i set UICollectionView height automatically inside UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to make my UICollectionView height automatically because the data inside the collection view cell is dynamic.
If i'm delegate the table view as `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, it'll not call the `cellForItemAtIndex`. But if i delegate the table view height, it'll call func `cellForItemAtIndex`, but the size'll be static.

How to make that height automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic CollectionViewCell In TableViewCell Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724530/dynamic-collectionviewcell-in-tableviewcell-swift)

Comment: i think you will require to add observer on 'contentSize' of collectionview.