# Non-Scrolling UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell Dynamic Height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have added `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell`, for that I have created `XIB` file. Check following image:

[image: UITableView Xib]

You can see in above image all view's hierarchy and constraints.

> **Note:** I have disable collection view vertical and horizontal
>   scrolling because I want to increase `UITableViewCell` height dynamically. So I have taken collection view's height's constraint's outlet and changing it programatically based on item available in collection view.

**Collection view's item size if fixed, width is proportional to collection view and height is 30**

I have register this xib with my table view by using following code.

```
self.tblSubCategory.register(SubCategoryTVC.Nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SubCategoryTVC")
```

Here is my code of `SubCategoryTVC`:

```
class SubCategoryTVC: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryView                 : UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryImageView            : UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imgCategory                  : UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblCategoryName              : UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var cvSubcategory                : UICollectionView!

    // MARK: Constrains's Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var const_cvSubcategory_height   : NSLayoutConstraint!


    class func Nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "SubCategoryTVC", bundle: nil)
    }

    func setCollectionView(dataSourceDelegate: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate, forRow row: Int) {
        self.cvSubcategory.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
        self.cvSubcategory.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
        self.cvSubcategory.tag = row
        self.cvSubcategory.reloadData()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

**UITableViewDataSource:**

```
extension SignupSecondStepVC: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SubCategoryTVC", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryTVC

        cell.lblCategoryName.text = "Category \(indexPath.row)"

        cell.cvSubcategory.register(SubCategoryCVC.Nib(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "SubCategoryCVC")

        return cell
    }
}
```

**UITableViewDelegate:**

```
extension SignupSecondStepVC: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        guard let subCategoryCell = cell as? SubCategoryTVC else { return }

        // This line of code set dataSource and delegate to `SignupSecondStepVC` instead of `SubCategoryTVC`
        subCategoryCell.setCollectionView(dataSourceDelegate: self, forRow: indexPath.row)

        subCategoryCell.cvSubcategory.setNeedsLayout()

        // This will change height of collection view based on item available.
        subCategoryCell.const_cvSubcategory_height.constant = 30 * 5

        subCategoryCell.cvSubcategory.setNeedsLayout()
        subCategoryCell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

Above code for `UITableView`, Please see following code of `UICollectionView`

**UICollectionViewDataSource:**

```
extension SignupSecondStepVC: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SubCategoryCVC", for: indexPath) as! SubCategoryCVC

        cell.btnSelection.setCornerRadius(radius: cell.btnSelection.frame.size.height / 2)
        cell.lblSubCategoryName.text = "SubCategory \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
}
```

**UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout:**

```
extension SignupSecondStepVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let width = collectionView.frame.size.width
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 30)
    }
}
```

After all these things done, I have issue with cell loading and UI. When I run app and load data first time getting issue of UI and not proper data loading. See following video, So you can understand my actual issue.

[Issue Video](https://youtu.be/l-pbQIc0CVA)

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Return any value in `estimatedHeightForRowAt` like 40, 50.

Comment: @dahiya_boy, I have tried `estimatedHeightForRowAt`, but it's not working.

Comment: Just try, in `setCollectionView` before reload call `self.LayoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: @dahiya_boy, I have tried above, but It's not working.

Comment: Please share sample project with same conditions and issue. Will check for you.

Comment: @dahiya_boy, I have created sample app, please download from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pwjRgQb-2dRIyfc-5LppBvMH2IkOJvEQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Check this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIKSc.png)  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRroK.png) images. Totally dynamic based on cell size. If its fine then I will add answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189678/discussion-between-mayur-karmur-and-dahiya-boy).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to bind your collectionView delegate/datasource with TableViewCell and need to use below func in tableViewcell. Make sure to turn off the CollectionView Scrolling.

```
override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {

    self.layoutIfNeeded()
    let contentSize = self.cvSubcategory.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
    if self.cvSubcategory.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) < 4 {
        return CGSize(width: contentSize.width, height: 120) // Static height if colview is not fitted properly.
    }

    return CGSize(width: contentSize.width, height: contentSize.height + 20) // 20 is the margin of the collectinview with top and bottom
}
```

Your project sample solution : https://github.com/thedahiyaboy/DynamicCollectionApp

---

For future purpose you can take ref from this post : [Dynamic CollectionViewCell In TableViewCell Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724530/dynamic-collectionviewcell-in-tableviewcell-swift)